# How to find a specific value in a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

lets say for example we had a list of lists and I wanted to find out what was at position x:

```
((a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i),(i,x,l))
```

how would I find out what is there and save it to a variable?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. It isn't clear what exactly your issue is.

Comment: I edited it but it may be still unclear. I have a tuple of tuples, and I want to find out the value of position x.

Comment: "Value _of position_ `x`"? This is what you need to clarify. Is `x` in your "mock input" the value you are looking for the position of?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't understand what you meant at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystuff = (('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i'),('i','x','l'))
lookfor = 'f' # example
for i, a in enumerate(mystuff):
     if lookfor in a:
         print('found {} in tuple {} at index {}'.format(lookfor, i, a.index(lookfor)))
```

output:

```
found f in tuple 1 at index 2
```

Comment: How would I manipulate that code to save what ever is in that position. Lets say that there is a word in every first position of tuple ( a , d , g , i ) and I wanted to print out the word in those positions, how would I do that?

Comment: @simons21, so the first index of each tuple is a word, and you want to print out the first index of each tuple?

Comment: bit stupid of me to use a word as an example, so ill tell you what I really need it for. I have a list of records from a sql query in a list called list1. I know that each list only has 4 items in it, and the first one is the date. I want to be able to select each date from each tuple and print them out first.

Comment: @simons21, if I understand correctly what you are asking, add `print(a[0])` as the first line under the `for`-loop in my code - will print out the first index of each tuple, regardless if the string you're searching for is in the tuple or not. If that's not what your describing, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42679861/edit) your question and include more info or an explicit example, and I'll gladly try to help.

Comment: don't need to, it worked, thanks for explaining it well:)

Comment: great, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how you would find items at index in list of lists

```
list_of_lists=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['i','x','l']]

#create variable consisting of sublist 2
find_sublist_two = (list_of_lists)[1]

print (find_sublist_two)

#create variable consisting of 2nd item of sublist 2
find_2nd_item_in_sublist_two = (list_of_lists)[1][1]

print (find_2nd_item_in_sublist_two)
```

Comment: would this work if I didn't know where an item was in one of the tuples?